# In Star Trek : Nemesis, why was B4 disassembled and why was Picard attacked while on the planet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In [Start Trek : Nemesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Nemesis) when Picard, Data and Worf go to Kolarus III to find the source of a signal, they found a disassembled android. Since Shinzon actually *intended* Picard to find the android, why was it disassembled and buried? Also, who attacked them while on the planet? Were they of the Reman race or where they the locals of the planet? Shinzon wanted to meet Picard so I don't think he had intended for this to happen.

[image]

Comment: Try to restrict questions to questions : "I hate when this happens" is a rant, not a question.

Comment: This is technically two questions: "Why was B4 hidden?" and "Why was Picard attacked?" You should limit each question to only one question, and feel free to create a new question with the other.

Answer (score 3):

Question 1: no canonical answer is available. Logically it can be assumed that B4 was disassembled to make the discovery less suspicious: a complete, intact android being found would raise questions, especially when it's common knowledge that that Soong dismantled all of his prototypes (at least it's common knowledge to people with any experience of Data's history - where Shinzon may have got this information is anyone's guess).

Ultimately, Question 1 highlights one of many inconsistencies in what is a rather poor script with many plot holes. The basic, unhelpful answer is "it was in the script". Sadly, there doesn't seem to be a canonical reason.

Question 2: Kolaran natives attacked them. It says so [here on Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Nemesis?action=edit&section=5):

> However, just as the searchers find the final piece, they come under
>   attack from Kolaran natives in vehicles of their own, so Picard drives
>   the Argo back to the shuttle while Worf mans the phaser cannon.

Comment: Is the assumption Kolaran natives are hostile to outsiders?

Comment: All of the TNG movies have glaring plot holes. It's best not to think too critically when watching.